# How to apply the same transform to many similarly-named xml files with one transform

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to change an attribute to a certain value in several .xml files all at once using one xslt.  The filenames all begin with a common phrase and end with a unique number (such as abc01.xml, abc02.xml, abc03.xml, etc.).  Is there a way to target a collection of .xml files like this with one xsl transform?

Here is what I've tried so far, which doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template select="document(../SavedDashboards/*.xml)" match="Tab/@Caption">
      <xsl:attribute name="Caption">Dashboard</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:document>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There are several ways you could process multiple input files, but unless you are using XSLT 2.0 (or an XSLT 1.0 processor that supports multiple result documents as an extension), the output will be a single document.

Comment: And, I did delete that superfluous xsl:document line..., but to no avail.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I suggest you have a look at the `collection()` function and the `xsl:result-document` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the XSLT processor you use, for instance Saxon 9 as documented at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.html allows you to process a directory of files if you call it as e.g. `java -jar saxon9.jar -s:inputDirectoryName -o:outputDirectoryName -xsl:sheet.xsl`. And your stylesheet `sheet.xsl` would then simply do

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Tab/@Caption">
      <xsl:attribute name="Caption">Dashboard</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So, if this transform is placed in a directory containing multiple .xml files having elements that match the template, the processor should execute the transform on all of them?

Comment: It is not the stylesheet code that I posted that applies it to all files in a directory, it is the command line to Saxon 9 that does that.

Comment: Actually, we are using an instance of XslCompiledTransform in a vb.net module in Visual Studio.

Comment: Then you will have to write VB.NET code to apply your XSLT to each file you want it to be applied to. `XslCompiledTransform` is an XSLT 1.0 processor, so even if you could load all documents in a single transformation you could only create a single output file.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Makes total sense.